# connected to database but can't getting data result method throwing nullpointer exception

Tags: java, database

i am using wildfly 10.1.0 my project is running well but when i try to validate username and password by retrieving data from database i get null pointer exception as follow.

```html
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.revguru.crs.web.user.controller.UserLoginController.authenticate(UserLoginController.java:86)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)
 at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
 at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
 at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
 at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
 at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
 at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
 at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
 at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
 ... 50 more
```

when i ping my database is shows me it is connected but still my UerLoginController class having securityService.authenticate(username,password) method call throws null pointer exception

**UerLoginController class**

```html
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.revguru.crs.core.entity.ht.HotelDataObject;
import com.revguru.crs.core.service.exception.HSDServiceException;
import com.revguru.crs.core.service.sc.SecurityService;
import com.revguru.crs.core.util.HSDServiceConstants;
import com.revguru.crs.security.entity.FeatureDataObject;
import com.revguru.crs.security.entity.HotelUserDataObject;
import com.revguru.crs.security.entity.RoleDataObject;
import com.revguru.crs.security.entity.UserDataObject;
import com.revguru.crs.web.common.vo.CommonGlobalBean;
import com.revguru.crs.web.constants.HSDWebConstants;
import com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.controller.GeneralHotelController;
import com.revguru.crs.web.hotel.delegate.HotelDelegate;
import com.revguru.crs.web.user.delegate.UserDelegate;
import com.revguru.crs.web.user.vo.Menu;
import com.revguru.crs.web.user.vo.MenuItem;
import com.revguru.crs.web.user.vo.UserInformation;
import com.revguru.crs.web.user.vo.UserLogin;
import com.revguru.crs.web.utils.Util;

public class UserLoginController {
 
 private FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
 HttpSession session = (HttpSession)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
 private SecurityService securityService = new SecurityService() ;
 
 public void setSecurityService(SecurityService securityService) {
  this.securityService = securityService;
 }
 
 public SecurityService getSecurityService() {
  return this.securityService;
 }
 
 /**
  * Authenticate the User
  * @return 
  */
 public String authenticate() {
  
  if(session.getAttribute("menus") != null) {
   session.removeAttribute("menus");
  }
  
  if (session.getAttribute("CommonGlobalBean") != null) {
   session.removeAttribute("CommonGlobalBean");
  }
  
  CommonGlobalBean commonGlobalBean = new CommonGlobalBean();
  commonGlobalBean.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault().getID());

  UserLogin userLogin = new UserLogin();
  userLogin = (UserLogin)session.getAttribute("UserLogin");
  
  String username = userLogin.getUserName();
  String password = userLogin.getPassword();
  
  UserInformation userInformation = null; 
  
  if (userLogin != null) {
   if (securityService.authenticate(username,password)) {
    Util.log("Get User Object by Email");
    UserDataObject userDataObject = securityService.getUserObjectByEmail(userLogin.getUserName());
    Util.log("User name : "+userDataObject.getUserFirstName());
    userInformation = (UserInformation)session.getAttribute("UserObject");
    if (userInformation != null) {
     session.removeAttribute("UserObject");
    }
    userInformation = getUserInformation(userDataObject);
    session.setAttribute("UserObject", userInformation);
      
    if(!checkUserAsHotelRole(userInformation)) {
     Util.log("User does not have hotel role.");
     Util.reportError(facesContext, "login_user_not_valid_password", null);
    }
```

this is my method definition

```html
public boolean authenticate(String email, String password) {
  log.info("Authenticating : " + email);
  UserDataObject user = new UserDataObject();
   user=getUserObjectByEmail(email);
  if (user == null) {
   log.info("User does not exist for email id :" + email);
   return false;
  }
  return checkPassword(password, user.getPassword());
 }
```

Comment: what's the line you are getting the error at?

Comment: at this line                                                                                                                      if (securityService.authenticate(username,password)) {

Answer (score 0):

The following lines are problematic:

```
UserLogin userLogin = new UserLogin();
userLogin = (UserLogin)session.getAttribute("UserLogin");
```

In the first line, you assign a reference to a new UserLogin object to the variable `userLogin`.

In the second line, you replace that reference with a reference to the object present in the session under the key "UserLogin".

If the session does not contain an attribute with the key "UserLogin", the result would be `null`, leading to a NullpointerException in the line right below it: `String username = userLogin.getUserName();`.

As for the place where you indicated the issue would have been: assuming neither `username` nor `password` are `null`, the issue would be inside `authenticate(String, String)`, of which you have not provided us with the code.

Comment: will you please elaborate your answer i am not getting it